# Does github's wiki supports header?

Tags: github, gollum-wiki

Githus uses [gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) to renders it's wikis. [It's features says](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki#subpages) that it supports `_Header`, `_Sidebar` and `_Footer`.

I have a wiki with `_Sidebar` and it works, but does github supports `_Header`?

Answer (score 0):

> but does github supports `_Header`?

Apparently so. See "[Adding a Table of Contents to your Github Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20161224093728/http://blackbe.lt/github-wiki-sidebar-table-contents-header-footer/)"

> ### How to Add a Header
>
> - Checkout your repository wiki via git. To find the URL, navigate to your wiki page in your browser and click the tab for Git Access.
> - Now that you have pulled down a local copy of your github repo wiki, create a new file in the repo called `_Header.md`
> - Within the newly created `_Header.md` file, you can add appropriate wiki syntax to your liking.
> - Add your new file to git via git add `_Header.md`, commit via git commit _Header.md -m "Adding new header.", and push via `git push origin master`.

Comment: thanks for sharing this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @fold since this answer is 14 months old, maybe something has changed since then.

Comment: I just tried it again today and it is not working. `_Header` file is not shown as header in a github wiki. Only `_Footer` and `_Sidebar` is working.